# Giving duplicates in Excel a unique identifier

Tags: excel

I have a large excel spreadsheet containing multiple address lines.  Many of these adress lines contain duplicate postcodes, with differing steet adrresses.

I need to seperate out each of these duplicates onto different spreadhseets, so that no one spreadhseet contains the same postcode.  I'm currently using an =if() statement to identify the duplicates, then cutting and poasting, and repeating almost ad infinitum to speperate them all out

as an example:

```
address 1 postcode 1
address 2 postcode 1
address 3 postcode 1
address 4 postcode 2
address 5 postcode 2
address 6 postcode 3
address 7 postcode 3
address 8 postcode 3
address 9 postcode 3
```

would give 4 spreadsheets:

```
1)
address 1 postcode 1
address 4 postcode 2
address 6 postcode 3
2)
address 2 postcode 1
address 5 postcode 2
address 7 postcode 3
```

etc

Any hints on a vb script?

Many thanks

Nick

Comment: Hi Nick,

If I'm correct, you want your big spreadsheet split into many spreadsheets. Each spreadsheet will only ever have unique post codes?
Just so I understand, what is the reson behind this?

Comment: Yup - thats pretty much it... the example didnt really come out quite how I expected, lol...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a one-off thing, then I'd consider doing it in the worksheet and bulk cut-pasting. I'd try something like this:

1. Sort my data on the post code column
2. In a new column, add a function to count the number of post codes below the current row that are duplicates of the code on that row (see below)
3. Save (copy/paste-special-values) the values obtained
4. Sort by duplicate number
5. Cut and paste blocks by duplicate number to new sheets

Say I have 20 values between 1 and 5 in column G. I put the following formula in H1:

```
=SUM(IF(G1:$G$20=G1,1,0))
```

... and (important bit) enter it as an *array formula* using **Control+Shift+Enter**. Now I copy that formula down (for speed, double-click the "fill handle" on the bottom right-hand corner of the cell). Here's my result:

```
1   2
1   1
2   2
2   1
3   8
3   7
3   6
3   5
3   4
3   3
3   2
3   1
4   2
4   1
5   6
5   5
5   4
5   3
5   2
5   1
```

Now I can copy column H and Edit...Paste Special...Values to fix the values. Sort by H to get this:

```
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   2
5   2
3   3
5   3
3   4
5   4
3   5
5   5
3   6
5   6
3   7
3   8
```

Now I have sets of records to copy to each of the 8 sheets that I now know are needed.

Of course, if you're going to be doing this a lot, then a macro would be useful. It needn't be much more complex than automating the above.

Comment: Mike - fantastic.. thankyou :)

I'll see if I can record a macro to this - we have to do this fairly often, but that formula's great :)